# Getting bytes between 2 indices

Tags: c#

i used to do it with a for loop in C and i wrote this extention method for c#

```
 public static byte[] GetBytes(this byte[] Bytes, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (startIndex > endIndex)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("start Index has to be bigger than the end Index");
    if (endIndex > Bytes.Length-1)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("end index is bigger than ArrayLength");

    byte[] bytes = new byte[endIndex - startIndex];
    for (int i=startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        bytes[i-startIndex] = Bytes[i];
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

but what is the built in .NET method to do that in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Array.Copy(Bytes, startIndex, destArray, 0, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Or you can user a bit of LINQ:

```
var destArray = Bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex).ToArray();
```

Or you can even use [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) if you do not need to/want to create a new array:

```
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(Bytes, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Comment: tried ArraySegment<byte>, its cool too but generic required me to write ArraySegment<byte>

Answer (score 3):

In case of arrays, you can use `Array.Copy` method instead of LINQ, which seems to be more clear than using `Skip` and `Take`:

```
public static byte[] SubArray(this byte[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[endIndex - startIndex];
    Array.Copy(array, startIndex, result, 0, endIndex - startIndex);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use LINQ:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex).ToArray();
}
```

Of course, you'd still have to include your error checking.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
return bytes.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex-startIndex).ToArray();
```